# Setting TFS 2013 SharePoint configuration without using GUI

Tags: sharepoint

I need to add the TFS SharePoint Web Application Settings, but without going through the GUI in the TFS Admin Console.

Having another issue preventing the GUI part from taking what I enter.

Can this be done in the DB or config file some where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We only have command `TFSConfig unattend /unattend /type:SPExtensions` to configure the SharePoint Extensions for Team Foundation Server. But there is no command to add the TFS SharePoint Web Applications. The only way I've known is use TFS Admin Console to add SharePoint Web Applications.